# I need help to change my IF statement method to SWITCH case in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm working on a project on Android Studio and I'm trying to create a filter. I added some `Checkboxes` to it and I would like to filter my `RecyclerView` with it. With `IF` statement I can do it, but as I understand for many `IF-ELSE` statements is better to use `SWITCH`. Therefore I would like to change my `IF` statement to SWITCH case but I don't know how to implement this method in Android Studio.

There is the code:

```
btnApply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(check_spring.isChecked() && check_summer.isChecked() && check_autumn.isChecked() && check_winter.isChecked()) {
            addAllplaces();
        } else if (check_spring.isChecked() && check_summer.isChecked() && check_autumn.isChecked()) {
            removeAllplaces();
            addSpring();
            addSummer();
            addAutumn();
            removeWinter();
        }
```

And I would like to use like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.check_spring:
            if (checked) {
                removeAllplaces();
                addSpring();
                removeSummer();
                removeAutumn();
                removeWinter();
            } else
                addAllplaces();

            removeSpring();
            removeSummer();
            removeAutumn();
            removeWinter();
            break;
}
```

Comment: What is btnApply? If it is a button, then how are you casting a view which is a button to a checkbox **boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked()** inside on click listener?

Comment: Yes, this is actually, where I got stuck. I find out how could I code a switch case statement but I don`t know how could I implement the method. Do I need to mention somehow in the OnCreate method?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is checking all the possible combinations of the states of the buttons. That is 2^4 = 16 states, so you would need 16 if conditions to check all those possible states. However, in your case, button states don't depend on each other, i.e. You can check each button state alone and do the corresponding logic.

Why don't you change the logic to the following:

1. At the beginning, remove all places
2. for each button, if it is checked, then add its corresponding place/season.

So the code might look like this:

```
removeAllPlaces();

if(check_spring.isChecked())
    addSpring();

if(check_autumn.isChecked())
    addAutumn();

if(check_winter.isChecked())
    addWinter();

if(check_summer.isChecked())
    addSummer();

// after the above code is executed, only the places for the checked buttons are added.
```

Comment: Abdelrahman Abdelnabi thank you for you answer. I tried this way but it is not the way as I would like to use the filter. At the beginning would be all the places and the filter would show only those objects, which were selected only or in combination/s.  I have other options as well on the filter which would take 100 if else statements and this is why I would like to use switch case instead.